# MDC: How to style label text?

Tags: html, css, mdc-components

How do I style [label](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/floating-label/) color?

[image]

The following code doesn't work:

```
<style>
.mdc-floating-label{
   color: #808080;
}
.mdc-floating-label--float-above{
  color:  #808080;
}
.mdc-floating-label--shake{
  color:  #808080;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try adding `!important` at the end of color value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `!important` at the end of color values.

```
<style>
.mdc-floating-label{
   color: #808080 !important;
}
.mdc-floating-label--float-above{
  color:  #808080 !important;
}
.mdc-floating-label--shake{
  color:  #808080 !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using !important as it's considered as a bad practice. Instead you can give your class more weight with something like:

```
<style>
label.mdc-floating-label{
   color: #808080;
}
label.mdc-floating-label--float-above{
  color:  #808080;
}
label.mdc-floating-label--shake{
  color:  #808080;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add **!important** because it is not as per standard css. Add parent class hierarchy it will definitely work.

```
<style>
.mdc-text-field label.mdc-floating-label{
  color: #808080;
}
.mdc-text-field label.mdc-floating-label--float-above{
 color:  #808080;
}
.mdc-text-field label.mdc-floating-label--shake{
 color:  #808080;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this:

```
.mdc-text-field--focused:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label {
  color: orange;
}
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-text-field__input:required ~ .mdc-floating-label::after,
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-text-field__input:required ~ .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-floating-label::after {
  color: orange;
}
```

It works, but ugly :(

If any one know how to use `--float-above` API, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

In your .css file you have to add/change this rows:

```css
.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-text-field__input,
.mdc-text-field--focused:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
}

.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled)+.mdc-text-field-helper-line .mdc-text-field-helper-text,
.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.mdc-text-field .mdc-text-field__input {
  caret-color: white;
  caret-color: var(--mdc-theme-surface, white);
}

.mdc-text-field--filled .mdc-line-ripple::after {
  border-bottom-color: white;
  /* @alternate */
  border-bottom-color: var(--mdc-theme-surface, white);
}

.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-color: white;
    /* @alternate */
    border-color: var(--mdc-theme-surface, white);
}
```

You can change the white color with your favorite color but keep in mind to change the var `--mdc-theme-surface` as well.
I tried this solution with [Material Component version 11.0.0](https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@11.0.0/dist/material-components-web.css) and [12.0.0](https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@12.0.0/dist/material-components-web.css)